# Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/view_preprocessed/html/C:" cannot b e created

Tags: php, magento

Everytime I try to use this command in my console  `php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy` I get this error, I have try almost everything creating the folder manually, updating composer, deleting the var/cache and even modifying  app/etc.di.xml and nothing. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTucd.png)

Comment: C: at the end of path looks wrong, probably you misconfigured it somewhere

Comment: I have try to look out for that config file as well, but I could not find it.

Comment: @alejandro-jimenez Have you already solved this problem? I also have run in this error. only on localhost/XAMPP though. When installing magento in a virtual box this error is not showing.